# Is a subset a vector space if it is just one vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm beginning to learn linear algebra and wanted to know if a subset of a vector space is a vector space if there is only one vector. For example, 
$$V = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3| x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0\}$$

Comment: Just check the vector space axioms if in doubt.

Comment: And as an exercise, prove vadim123's answer!

Answer (score 4):

$V$ is a single vector: $$V=\{(0,0,0)\}$$
This is a vector space if that single vector is the origin, which it is in this case.  If it were any other single vector, then no it is not a vector space.